# Bonsai elasticsearch vs Amazon elasticsearch price/month comparison?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

Does anyone here can help me compare the price/month of these two elasticsearch hosting services?

Specifically, what is the equivalent of the [Bonsai10](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/bonsai?utm_swu=816) that costs $50/month when compared to the amazon elasticsearch [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/pricing/)?

I just want to know which of the two services saves me money on a monthly basis for my rails app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bonsai10 is 8 core 1GB memory 10GB disk, limited to 20 shards & 1 million documents.

Amazon's AES doesn't have comparable sizing/pricing. All will be more expensive.
If you want 10GB of storage, you could run a single m3.large.elasticsearch (2 core 7.5GB memory, 32GB disk) at US$140/month.
If you want 8 cores, single m3.2xlarge.elasticsearch (8 core 30GB memory, 160GB disk) at US$560/month.

Elastic's cloud is more comparable. 1GB memory 16GB disk will run US$45/month. They don't publish the CPU count.

Out of the other better hosted elasticsearch providers (because they list actual resources you receive, full list below), qbox offers the lowest cost comparable plan for US$40/month for 1GB memory 20GB disk. No CPU count  https://qbox.io/pricing

Objectrocket
Compose.io (an IBM company)
Qbox
Elastic